# Отображение количества столкновений объектов

Tags: flash, разработка-игр

У меня возникла проблема при написании игры на As 3.0. Как сделать, чтобы после столкновения объекта с другим объектом надпись 0 вверху увеличивалась каждый раз на 1, а сам объект менял свою позицию? Объект позицию меняет, но я не совсем понимаю как сделать чтобы число написанное вверху программы увеличивалось при этом на 1? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я новичок, так что не пинайте, а просто объясните, как сделать это правильно.

Answer (score 1):

У текстового поля с "0" укажите имя, к примеру: scores

В коде, при столкновении (я так понимаю, вы его уже отслеживаете через hitTest), вписываем:

```
scores.text = String(int(scores.text) + 1);
```

это самый быстрый, но не самый разумный метод. Что происходит: scores.text - берем текст поля, превращаем его в число (int(scores.text)), прибавляем 1 (int(scores.text) + 1), переводим в строку (String(int(scores.text) + 1)), полученное записываем в поле (scores.text = String(int(scores.text) + 1)).

Если хотите сделать получше:
В самом начале кода заводим переменную

```
var points:int = 0;
```

При столкновении, прибавляем 1, и записываем в поле:

```
points++;
scores.text = String(points);
```

("points++" - аналог "points = points + 1" - прибавление единицы)

Плюсы второго метода: очки столкновений хранятся отдельно, и нет шанса глюка, при изменении содержимого текстового поля. Плюс, эти очки можно использовать далее.

Напомню еще раз: scores - это имя текстового поля. У вас оно может быть другим.